# how to change words with the same words but with number at the back bash

Tags: bash

I have a file for example with the name file.csv and content

```
adult,REZ
man,BRB
women,SYO
animal,HIJ
```

and a line that is nor a directory nor a file

```
file.csv BRB1 REZ3 SYO2
```

And what I want to do is change the content of the file with the words that are on the line and then get the nth letter of that word with the number at the end of the those words in capital
and the output should then be

```
umo
```

I know that I can get over the line with

```
for i in "${@:2}"
do
words+=$(echo "$i ")
done
```

and then the output is

```
REZ3 BRB1 SYO2
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: What's the field separator of your CSV?

Comment: a comma between the words

Comment: I would do the following algorithm: From your single line, create an associative array mapping the keys (REZ, BRB,...) to their values (3, 1, ...). Then I would loop over the lines of the file, tearing apart each line into fields. From the second field (i.e. REZ) you first get the associated number from your associative array (i.e. 3). Then you use this number to extract the respective character (i.e. the 3rd) from the first field. You do this for each line and accumulate the resulting characters into a single string.

Comment: `words+=$(echo "$i ")` is useless and doesn't make any sense for what you're trying to solve.

Comment: Split lines by commas using `IFS=,` and the `read` command. Use an associative array, use the second column as keys and the first column as values. Store the file contents that way. Take each command line token, extract its leading letters (e.g. by `"${token%%+([0-9])}"` (with `extglob` shell option) or by index if it is known `"${token::3}"`). Similarly, extract the trailing number; there is a `#` equivalent to `%`. Next, use the letters to look up the first column’s value in the associative array keyed by the second column. Then extract the desired character as `"${value:index:1}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

Pass the string of values as an awk variable and then split them into an array `a`.  For each record in file.csv, iterate this array and if the second field of current record matches the first three characters of the current array value, then strip the target character from the first field of the current record and append it to a variable.   Print the value of the aggregated variable.

```
awk -v arr="BRB1 REZ3 SYO2" -F, 'BEGIN{split(arr,a," ")} {for (v in a) { if ($2 == substr(a[v],0,3)) {n=substr(a[v],length(a[v]),1); w=w""substr($1,n,1) }}} END{print w}' file.csv
umo
```

You can also put this into a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

words="${2}"
src_file="${1}"

awk -v arr="$words" -F, 'BEGIN{split(arr,a," ")} \
     {for (v in a) { \
          if ($2 == substr(a[v],0,3)) { \
               n=substr(a[v],length(a[v]),1); \
               w=w""substr($1,n,1); 
          }
     }
} END{print w}' "$src_file"
```

Script execution:

```
./script file.csv "BRB1 REZ3 SYO2"
umo
```

Comment: But this doesn't work when I do this                                                                          
 for i in "${@:2}"
do 
words=$(echo "$i" | grep -oE '[A-Z]+')
awk -v arr=$(echo "$words" -F, 'BEGIN{split(arr,a," ")} {for (v in a) { if ($2 == substr(a[v],0,3)) {n=substr(a[v],length(a[v]),1); w=w""substr($1,n,1) }}} END{print w}' $1)
echo $arr
done

Comment: Paste that code into shellcheck.net and make the recommended changes.  The code in your comment has some errors.  Further, how are you calling this code?

Comment: See updated answer for use inside of bash script

Comment: No sorry doesn't work. Do you know what needs to change in the code above?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not useful information.   The code produces the expected output for me based upon the inputs in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A idx_dic
filename="$1"
pattern_string=""
for i in "${@:2}";
do
    pattern_words=$(echo "$i" | grep -oE '[A-Z]+')
    index=$(echo "$i" | grep -oE '[0-9]+')
    pattern_string+=$(echo "$pattern_words|")
    idx_dic["$pattern_words"]="$index"
done
pattern_string=${pattern_string%|*}
while IFS= read -r line
do
    line_pattern=$(echo $line | grep -oE $pattern_string)
    [[ -n $line_pattern ]] && line_index="${idx_dic[$line_pattern]}" && echo $line | awk -v i="$line_index" '{split($0, chars, ""); printf("%s", chars[i]);}'
done < $filename
```

- first find the capital words pattern and catch the index corresponding
- then construct the hole pattern words string which connect with `|`
- at last, iterate the every line according to the pattern string, and find the letter by the index

Execute this `script.sh` like:

```
bash script.sh file.csv BRB1 REZ3 SYO2
```

Comment: The only problem is that you ordered them alphabetically. How can you maintain it in the same order? Thank you

Comment: @GJO2 I don't order them alphabetically, just obtain them line by line, and get the result `umo` what you want. If there is anything not suitable with your cases, please let me know.

Comment: That’s a lot of `fork()`s for every single item. Explicit pipes can be avoided using `grep ... <<< "$i"`. Entire `grep` processes can be avoided using Bash alone, e.g. `pattern_words="${i/+([0-9])}"; index="${i/+([A-Z])}";` (assuming `shopt -s extglob`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a way using sed.
Create a pattern string from command arguments and convert lines with sed.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"
pat='s/^/ /;Te;'
for i in ${@:2}; do
    pat+=$(echo $i | sed 's#^\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9]*\)$#s/.\\{\2\\}\\(.\\).*,\1$/\\1/;#')
done
pat+='Te;H;:e;${x;s/\n//g;p}'
eval "sed -n '$pat' $file"
```